# error in running java file using another java file

Tags: java, error-handling

I am actually trying to run my java file using another java file in windows....and this is my code:

```
private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(ins));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + line);
    }
  }

  private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
      String s=System.getProperty("user.dir");
      s="C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\\webapps\\Mazil4.0\\WEB-INF\\classes";
  File workingDir = new File(s);
  System.out.println(q);
  //new Foo().nonStaticMethod();
Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command,null,workingDir);

printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
pro.waitFor();
System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());


 }


  public static void mai(String[] args) {

      String[] credentials=new String[4];int k=0;
      for (String s: args) {
          System.out.println(s);
        credentials[k]=s;k++;
    if(k==4)
    break;
      }


    try {
      //runProcess("javac test2.java");
        //thread foo=new thread();
      runProcess("java mainclasses.emaildownload "+credentials[0]+" "+credentials[1]+" "+credentials[2]+" "+credentials[3]+" ");

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }System.out.println("hI");
  }
```

I am giving the location of class by using workingDir...and my file path is:

```
C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\Mazil4.0\WEB-INF\classes\mainclasses\emaildownload.class
```

package name is mainclasses.but it still gives error:

```
could not find or load main class mainclasses.emaildownload
```

whay could possibly be the reason?

Comment: Is emaildownload main class name?

Answer (score 0):

IN this line:

```
public static void mai(String[] args) {
```

is an 'n' missing.

Change to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: thats not the problem actually I am using it in jsp so I want it this way only

Comment: YOu call the main method from jsp?

Comment: what I do is thread.mai(id); where thread is the class name and id of type String[]

Answer (score 0):

I belive command should look like:

```
java -cp <path-to-jar> <main-class>
```

Providing that:

1. main class you whish to load: mainclasses.emaildownload
   (class emaildownload in package mainclasses)
2. patch to jar containing given
   main class:
   C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\Mazil4.0\WEB-INF\classes\

command should look like:

```
java -cp C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\Mazil4.0\WEB-INF\classes\<jar-file> mainclasses.emaildownload
```

or you can use wildcard:

```
java -cp "C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\Mazil4.0\WEB-INF\classes\*" mainclasses.emaildownload
```

Comment: What is wrong with this implementation and should it be like this: java -cp /././. mainclasses.emaildownload

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what do you mean. Are you asking a question? I'll update my post.